# Using site_url() but for the site before the page calling it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog on a multi blog wordpress site and im using site_url() or home_url()

The url it links is like www.example.com/name

I want it to link to www.example.com (not the /name!) everytime.

Is there a way to link it to the page like that?

Comment: what about `get_site_url();` function?

Comment: @jagad89 still the same url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`network_site_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_site_url) will get the URL of the main site in your network.

So if `example.com` is the main site, `network_site_url` will return the URL for `example.com` regardless of which site you call it from.